# How to setup an OTP Phone Authentication for Power Apps Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-ad-b2c, dynamics-365, powerapps-portal

What are the steps to enable an OTP Phone Authentication for Power Apps Portal?
My initial research (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/configure-portal-authentication) make me believe that I can setup Azure B2C for Authentication and in here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication-user-flows) shows that I can setup an OTP  only phone sign-in experience.

In context of Power Apps Portal that connected to a Dynamics 365. I wanted to do the followings:

1. Use Contact Record for Power Apps Portal User
2. Disable User Sign-up in Power Apps Portal
3. Invite Contact Record to sign in to the Portal
4. Contact that is invited to sign in to the Portal will be able to sign in using Phone Authentication (OTP only, if for the first time the contact needs to redeem the invitation that is also ok)

Is it by any chance possible to do (is my planned Flow logical?) and if it is, what are the steps that I need to take to achieve it?

Comment: The links you posted at correct to do the OTP auth with Power Apps through AAD B2C.

Comment: The documentation you have posted is the right start for you to take this forward. You can ''Get Started" from the next page itself on how to enable the auth provider for your app. Once the provider is connected and setup successfully, you can create flows in the Power Automate for the same to achieve what you want. Let me know if you want explanation further. You need to clarify a few details regarding your requirements.